# Keyboard input using JFrame and KeyAdapter

Tags: java, keyboard

hi everyone im using netbeans 7.2.1
and was following a tutorial for keyboard input

this code should draw a circle in JFrame, which it does
but then should take arrow key input to move it, which it does not

thank you for your help :)

```
package gamefirstclass;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFirstClass extends JFrame {
//Variables

    int y, x;
//Double Buffer
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

//Window Basics
    public GameFirstClass() {
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        setTitle("Add window title");
        setSize(800, 700);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        x = 150;
        y = 150;

    }
// main

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameFirstClass();
    }
    //Controls
    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == event.VK_LEFT)
            {
                x--;
            }
            if (keyCode == event.VK_RIGHT)
            {
                x++;
            }
            if (keyCode == event.VK_UP)
            {
                y--;
            }
            if (keyCode == event.VK_DOWN)
            {
                y++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        }
    }
//Double Buffer

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by getting a new tutorial. You should not be overriding the paint() method of a JFrame to do painting. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent). Then you add the panel to the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for examples and more information. Also, the tutorial you should read up on Key Bindings, which should generally be used instead of KeyListeners. Your key listeners won't work unless the component has focus.

Comment: @camickr Please make this the answer! It saved me a rant +1

Comment: And I second all that @camickr has to say. Please give those tutorials a read and then if still stuck, come on back with your new code and let's go over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so there is one problem: your `if statements!`.
Basically, in your `keyListener`, the `if statements` don't execute because of the `semicolon` after them.
The blocks are all that remain, and the modifications to `x` are the same.  Just remove those `semicolons` and I believe it will work.
Also, don't call `repaint()` from `paintComponent()`, because you are generating a lot of `repaints` for every time.  I don't know if this matters, but you should call `setFocusable(true)` on your `JFrame` to make sure that the `KeyListener` works.

Good Luck!